# Is it good to run "fsck" command in C++ code program before mounting a file system?

Tags: linux, aix, fsck

I am writing a C++ Library to attach/mount file systems present on Logical Volumes
in Linux and AIX.

Can I run/execute `fsck` command in the C++ code before mounting a file system?

What problems will arise if I execute `fsck` command in C++ code on Linux and AIX?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to always run `fsck` before each mount. Some FS may take hours to fsck. It is better to check the state of the filesystem instead. If the state is not clean then run fsck, otherwise proceed with mount. On ext2/3/4, tune2fs can show the status of the filesystem.

Comment: I would not mount file systems from C++ code, but just run a configurable shell script doing that. Leave configuration of that script to the sysadmin. And document what your program is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you also tell me how to get state of filesystem in code after executing "fsck"

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you would probably have to run fsck in non-interactive mode, assuming the user is answering "yes"to all questions by running fsck -y.

This can lead to all sorts of unwanted behaviour if something nasty happens.

If you need to mount a filesystem in your C++ code, I would consider letting the OS and/or the mount command decide when fsck needs to be run (based on the number of previous mounts since the last fsck) and let it run in interactive mode, offering the user a possibility to  answer to the potential questions.